# Loop through object and check if field is an empty array and return null

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following object:

```
productDetails: {
    cislife: [],
    prime: []
  }
```

I want to return null instead of empty array if there aren't any values available.

e.g: I want to check if any of the arrays are empty and return null as the key value, either cislife or prime. If prime is populated and cislife is not then i would return the values for prime and null for cislife

Any ideas?

Comment: Please precise the problem. Where's the loop? Which array are you talking about - the `cislife` or `prime`?

Comment: Okay. I want to check if any of the arrays are empty and return null, either cislife or prime. If prime is populated and cislife is not then i would return the values for prime and null for cislife.

Comment: return... where? You have a function? Could you edit your question, and share our attempt, give the output for several border cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to produce the desired array without mutating the original one:

```js
const initialObject = {
  cislife: [],
  prime: [],
  nonArrayField: "I'm not an array, leave me alone!"
};

const resultObject = {
  ...initialObject,
  ...Object.keys(initialObject)
    // filter out keys that do not belong to empty arrays
    .filter(key => Array.isArray(initialObject[key]) && !initialObject[key].length)
    // replace empty arrays with nulls
    .reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: null }), {}),
};

console.log(resultObject);
```

Comment: Brilliant Answer

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this where you use `Array.prototype.reduce` and build out an object literal, replacing `[]` with `null` where appropriate:

```js
const productDetails = {
  cislife: [],
  prime: [],
  nonEmptyExample: [1, 2, 3],
  nonArrayExample: 'a string!'
};

const emptyArraysToNulls = o => {
  return Object.entries(productDetails).reduce((accum, entry) => {
    const [key, val] = entry;
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      accum[key] = val.length === 0 ? null : val;
    } else {
      accum[key] = val;
    }

    return accum;
  }, {});
};

console.log(emptyArraysToNulls(productDetails));
```

Comment: What if the object has other keys that are not arrays? 
like {
cislife: [],
 prime: [],
date: 'may 1, 2019'
}

Comment: Good point! - i modified the code to use `Array.isArray` to check and only act on array values - all other types will just be copied to the new object.

Comment: Yea this is perfect as well

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the object you can use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/get)

```js
var productDetails = {
  _cislife: [],
  get cislife() {
    return this._cislife.length ? this._cislife : null
  },
  _prime: [],
  get prime() {
    return this.prime.length ? this.prime : null
  },
}

console.log(productDetails.cislife)
```

Comment: Nice idea. But a more generic solution would be preferred

Answer (score 0):

You can use getter methods, like below:

```js
var productDetails = {
    _cislife: [],
    _prime: [],

    get cislife() {
        return this._cislife.length == 0 ? null : this._cislife;
    },

    get prime() {
        return this._prime.length == 0 ? null : this._prime;
    }
}

console.log(productDetails.cislife); // null
console.log(productDetails.prime); // null
```